# Vertex cutsets of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph with vertex set $[n]$. I say that a subset $S \subset [n]$ is a *cut set* of $G$ if $c(S \setminus \{i\})<c(S)$ for every $i \in S$, where $c(S)$ denotes the number of connected components of $G[[n] \setminus S]$ (the subgraph induced in $G$ by $[n] \setminus S$). I assume that the empty set is a cut set of any graph.

Is something known about cut sets of a graph (maybe under a different name)? If so, what are good references for this?

If I require that $G$ is bipartite and for every cut set $S$ of $G$, $c(S)=card(S)+1$, is it true that the intersection of any two cut sets is again a cut set?

I know that the answer to the last question is negative if $G$ is not bipartite or the other condition does not hold.

Thanks!

Comment: *Cut set* has the other [meaning][1] in graph theory.


  [1]: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CutSet.html

Comment: Thanks for the remark. I'm probably referring to the something similar to vertex cutsets, with an additional condition on the number of connected components

Comment: It is not a vertex cut set, but a set of vertices each of which is a cutpoint of subgraph. Anyway you have well defined and seemingly new object. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArticulationVertex.html